# fill tableview with mutable array

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios4, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

i've got a nsmutablearray which is filled by the user:

```
NSString *_string = _text.text;
[_array addObject:_string];
[self saveIt];
_text.text = @"";
```

_text is a textField, _array is a nsmutablearray

then i've got a method which saves the string in the nsuserdefaults:

```
-(void)saveIt {

NSUserDefaults *tableDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[tableDefaults setObject:_array forKey:@"key"];
```

}

well, how can i display the saved array in the tableview when the app is opened again ?

thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You load the array back out of NSUserDefaults, and use the array's contents to return the appropriate values from the various methods of the table view's [data source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), particularly `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

---

Quick example:

First, read the array back out of NSUserDefaults at some point, probably in your class's init or in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` (after calling NSUserDefaults's `registerDefaults:`, of course):

```
_array = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"key"]] retain];
```

Then use it for the mentioned methods:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _array.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

That should get you started. You'll probably also want to call `reloadData` or `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` on your table view when adding something to the array, see [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for details.

Comment: can you give me an example please? :)